# What is the best way to process times in awk and sponge the output to a new column in a csv file?

Tags: bash, awk

Pretend there is a simple csv file:

```
date,miles,time,min
2016-01-01,5.15,0:21:10,0:03:30
2016-01-03,15.30,1:10:00,0:03:45
2016-02-02,08.37,0:31:24,0:03:22
```

Say I want to add two more columns, in which the H:M:S times are converted to decimal numbers, where 1.0 equals one hour. How can I efficiently achieve this with awk? Currently I pipe a field of this file to another awk command where I use `:` as a field separator, use some arithmetic (e.g. field 2 divided by 60) to get the decimal numbers, save the results to a file, then use `paste` to combine the original and derived file. There is an easier way, no?

Comment: Yes. Use the `split` function to split the time fields into arrays. No need to sponge, even (if by that you mean read the results for the whole file into memory before printing anything).

Comment: a first step: `awk -F ',' '{OFS=","; print $1,$2,$3,$4,"foo"}' file`

Comment: could you be more specific, @triplee? I don't see how `split` applies to breaking up a field based on some delimiter.

Comment: You can use python to do it, it would be much easier.

Comment: @cfye14 Something like this: `split($3, a, ":");print a[1]+(a[2]+a[3]/60)/60` where `FS=","`

Comment: If the documentation for Awk's `split` function doesn't seem applicable, I don't think anything will.

Comment: @avivb that's a pretty big statement - care to show us how it'd be much easier in python? cfye14 - please edit your question to show us the expected output given that input.

Comment: oh lol, i was tired when i wrote that, i had just looked at `split` in bash ...

Comment: righto @triplee. That works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't show us your expected output, this may or may not be what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    if (NR==1) {
        tdec = "time_dec"
        mdec = "min_dec"
    }
    else {
        split($3,a,/:/); tdec = a[1] + a[2]/60 + a[3]/3600
        split($4,a,/:/); mdec = a[1] + a[2]/60 + a[3]/3600
    }
    print $0, tdec, mdec
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
date,miles,time,min,time_dec,min_dec
2016-01-01,5.15,0:21:10,0:03:30,0.352778,0.0583333
2016-01-03,15.30,1:10:00,0:03:45,1.16667,0.0625
2016-02-02,08.37,0:31:24,0:03:22,0.523333,0.0561111
```

but hopefully you get the idea if it's not exactly what you want.

Comment: Looking thru a couple awk questions, I see it is common to create an .awk file, then run that against the file-to-be-processed. Is this just cleaner, or random preference?

Comment: It's highly recommended for all scripts run under Windows due to Windows nightmarish quoting rules, only really recommended for larger scripts in UNIX otherwise it's mostly preference. The only functional difference is that an awk script in a file can use hard-coded single quote (`'`) chars since it's not single-quote-delimited. I use it a lot in answers to clearly separate the awk script from the setting of variables and/or file or other arguments when awk is invoked.

Comment: gotcha, makes sense.